# How to register Saxon/XSLT extension functions such that they accessible in BaseX/XQuery (JAXP APIs)

Tags: saxon, basex, xslt-3.0, jaxp

I have a few Saxon/XSLT extension functions that I created through the [simple interface](http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensibility/integratedfunctions/ext-simple-J) that I register like this:

```java
Processor proc = new Processor(false);
proc.registerExtensionFunction(myExtensionFunctionInstance);
```

Now I want to use that with BaseX, but I see that [BaseX instantiates its own Processor instance through JAXP APIs](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-core/src/main/java/org/basex/query/func/xslt/XsltTransform.java#L119):

```java
// Somewhere inside basex's XSLT transformer instantiation (see link above).
final TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

So it seems I need to find a way to change the factory that BaseX uses such that I can register my functions.

If I get it right I need to create my own factory implementation. Adapted from Saxon's [net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl](http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!configuration/config-interfaces/jaxp-configuration):

```java
package my.package;
public class MyOwnTrasnformerFactory extends SaxonTransformerFactory {
    public TransformerFactoryImpl() {
        super();
        ExtensionFunction myFunction = new MyExtFunction(...);
        this.processor.registerExtensionFunction(myFunction);
    }

    public TransformerFactoryImpl(Configuration config) {
        super(config);
        ExtensionFunction myFunction = new MyExtFunction(...);
        this.processor.registerExtensionFunction(myFunction);
    }
}
```

And then I could do:

```java
System.setProperty(
  "javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
  "my.package.MyOwnTrasnformerFactory");
```

- Doe this seem like a correct approach?
- Is there's an alternative way to create a single processor instance for the lifetime of my program without creating my custom factory? I'm using Clojure and [creating Java classes (genclass)](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/gen-class) is a bit less convenient and less dynamic.

Comment: So I guess this is the approach recommended by BaseX: 

https://docs.basex.org/wiki/XSLT_Module, it asks to set the system property:


```java
System.setProperty(
  "javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
  "org.custom.xslt.TransformerFactoryImpl");```

... so probably I *will* have to create that factory class...

Comment: That all looks feasible to me. Note that `SaxonTransformerFactory.processor` is private, but there is an accessor `getProcessor()`.

Comment: Thank you MIchael, I could actually make it work! I'll update the post as soon as i have a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing the solution described on my question... here's a full gist:

https://gist.github.com/EmmanuelOga/018ece8b4776636ce1ab3f73e215ce75

The relevant parts:

```clj
(ns rainbowfish.xslt-factory
  (:import [net.sf.saxon Configuration]
           [net.sf.saxon.lib Feature])
  (:gen-class
   :name rainbowfish.XsltFactory
   :extends net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory
   :post-init configure))

(defn -configure
  "Generated Java class will call this method right after
  construction. Here we get a chance to grab Saxon's processor for
  configuration purposes (for example, adding extension functions)."
  [this & args]
  (let [processor (.getProcessor this)]
    ;; Here we can do whatever we want to the processor,
    ;; For instance, register some extension functions.
    (doto processor
      (.registerExtensionFunction some-function))))
```

That defines the Java class `rainbowfish.XsltFactory` using clojure. Since it uses gen-class, it needs to be compiled by calling `compile('rainbowfish.xslt-factory)` or by asking lein to compile it, etc.

Now that we have a class that configures the XSLT processor, we need to inform BaseX that it should use it. BaseX reads the JAXP configuration for this. The configuration can be set like this:

```clj
(System/setProperty
     "javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
     "rainbowfish.XsltFactory")
```

... this should be called before creating an instance of the BaseX server. See the gist for more details!