# XSLT - Convert images (and pdf) to base64

Tags: html, css, xslt, saxon, apache-fop

I use Apache FOP 2.8 to transform Apache FOP [Intermediate Format (IF)](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/intermediate.html) file into a `HTML-file` with a self written xslt stylesheet.

As external libraries i have currently only saxon12he installed.

## The Problem #1 (image to base64)

In the source IF document there are image xml Elements that look like this:

```xml
<image xlink:href="files\Logo.png"/>
```

It would be easy to convert this to `HTML` and get an output like

```html
<img src="files\Logo.png"/>
```

when using a template like:

```xml
<xsl:template match="image">
    <xsl:variable name="file-path"><xsl:value-of select="@xlink:href"/></xsl:variable>
    <img src="{$file-path}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The Problem here is that the generated `HTML-file` can't be 'standalone'... means that besides the `HTML-file` there has to be the `files` directory with a `Logo.png` inside so that the `HTML-file` finds the imagepath `files\Logo.png`

But what i want to achieve is that the `HTML-file` is 'standalone'.

So is there a way to convert `Logo.png` to `Base64` maybe in a simple function call like:

```xml
<xsl:template match="image">
    <xsl:variable name="file-path"><xsl:value-of select="@xlink:href"/></xsl:variable>
    <img src="to-base64($file-path)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to create an output like:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA...."/>
```

## The Problem #2 (pdf to base64)

So another tricky part is, that in the intermediate format, the `xlink:href` can also lead to a `.pdf` file...

```xml
<image xlink:href="files\Table_1234.pdf"/>
```

It would be great if there is also the possibility to transform this into a base64 image in the same way like above.

Or maybe there is also another way to achieve the HTML document becomes 'standalone', but converting to base64 was the only idea i got so far.

## Approach 1 (Saxon Java extension function)

I tried creating a Java extension function for Saxon 12 HE following this [documentation](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/extensibility/extension-functions-J/ext-full-J.html)

So I've implemented a `ExtensionFunctionDefinition`

```java
import net.sf.saxon.expr.XPathContext;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.ExtensionFunctionCall;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.ExtensionFunctionDefinition;
import net.sf.saxon.om.Sequence;
import net.sf.saxon.om.StructuredQName;
import net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException;
import net.sf.saxon.value.SequenceType;
import net.sf.saxon.value.StringValue;

public class ImageToBase64 extends ExtensionFunctionDefinition {
    @Override
    public StructuredQName getFunctionQName() {
        return new StructuredQName("ext", "http://example.com/saxon-extension", "imageToBase64");
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType[] getArgumentTypes() {
        return new SequenceType[]{SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING};
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType getResultType(SequenceType[] suppliedArgumentTypes) {
        return SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING;
    }

    @Override
    public ExtensionFunctionCall makeCallExpression() {
        return new ExtensionFunctionCall() {
            @Override
            public Sequence call(XPathContext context, Sequence[] arguments) throws XPathException {
                var filePath = ((StringValue)arguments[0]).getStringValue();
                // open file and convert to base64 string
                var resultBase64 = "12345";
                return StringValue.makeStringValue(resultBase64);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Because the documentation says: "*the classes that implement these extension functions must be registered with the Configuration*" and this can be "*achieved by subclassing net.sf.saxon.Transform or net.sf.saxon.Query, overriding the method applyLocalOptions() so that it makes the appropriate calls on config.registerExtensionFunction();*" I also added a class that extends `net.sf.saxon.Transform`:

```java
import net.sf.saxon.Transform;
import net.sf.saxon.trans.CommandLineOptions;

public class Configuration extends Transform {
    @Override
    protected void applyLocalOptions(CommandLineOptions options, net.sf.saxon.Configuration config) {
        config.registerExtensionFunction(new ImageToBase64());
        super.applyLocalOptions(options, config);
    }
}
```

When i build the artifacts to get the `jar` file (i use `IntelliJ` btw.) i only added the "compile output" so the jar is 3kb in the end.

Then i dropped the jar into the lib folder next to `saxon-he-12.2.jar` of Apache FOP and added
`xmlns:ext="http://example.com/saxon-extension"` to the `xsl:stylesheet`.

But when i now call

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="ext:imageToBase64('my/file/path')"/>
```

I get the error `net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot find a 1-argument function named Q{http://example.com/saxon-extension}imageToBase64()`

Comment: Saxon HE does not support the EXPath file module (which should probably suffice to get a base64 representation of a binary image or pdf file: http://expath.org/spec/file#fn.read-binary) so you will have to decide whether you invest in a license for PE or whether you want to try to write your own integrated extension function(s) calling into Java: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/extensibility/extension-functions-J/

Comment: As i am more familiar with c# i tried following this guide: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/extensibility/extension-functions-CS/ext-fns-N.html

So i created a c# class library with nuget reference to SaxonHE 10.9.0 and created the class `Sqrt : ExtensionFunctionDefinition` and also the class `SqrtCall : ExtensionFunctionCall`. Then i built the project and put the `.dll` in the lib folder of FOP.

In my xslt stylesheet i referenced `xmlns:my="http://math.com/"` and called `my:sqrt(4)` but i still get the error Cannot find a 1-argument function named Q{http://math.com/}sqrt()

Comment: I would suggest to use the documentation of Saxon 10 if you want to work with Saxon 10; use the documentation for Saxon 11 if you want to work with Saxon 11. But expecting Apache FOP to use a .NET dll seems absurd. It is a Java tool and a Java library and any .NET tool or library you build can be used from .NET but not from Java, so you will need to write Java code for a Saxon HE Java extension (assuming you use Saxon Java with FOP).

Comment: ok that the FOP can not handle dlls makes sense of course... I have not thought about it before.
Then I try the whole thing again with java and then report back if necessary :P

Comment: Hey @MartinHonnen i edited my question and added `Approach 1 (Saxon Java extension function)`. Still not getting this to work... Maybe you could help me out here

Comment: I don't think FOP command line tool is going to use your specialized subclass with the extensions. How do you run FOP? From the command line e.g. https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.8/running.html#fop-script?

Comment: Yes. i do like `fop-2.8\fop\fop.bat -c "MyIF.if" -xsl "if2html.xsl" -foout "MyHtml.html"`.
I guess what you are going to say is that I have to create a saxon configuration file and give it in as a parameter?

Comment: I would suggest to first test with XSLT/Saxon command only that your extension is found and does the job to perform the conversion you want. I would suggest to raise the issue about using an integrated extension function to Saxon HE in a context where a (FOP) cmd probably calls Java and there simply the JAXP Transformer API is used as a different question. I am not sure there is a well established path here but of course the right search terms might turn up a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860654/how-to-register-saxon-xslt-extension-functions-such-that-they-accessible-in-base suggests you might be able to solve it by subclassing `SaxonTransformerFactory` and then by nominating your subclass on the java command line as e.g. `-Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=com.example.MyOwnTransformeFactory`. I am not sure the fop.cmd or fop.bat will pick that up but you could use an edited copy and make sure the line where the `java` command is called sets that property.

Comment: I just think i got it to work by creating a MyTransformerFactory like in your link and `set CUSTOMOPTS=-Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=ExtensionsPackage.MyTransformerFactory` to the `fop.bat`. 
My value-of now prints '12345' :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work with the help of @MartinHonnen who told me to create my own extension function.

So i created a new java program (it's important to use Java 8) and added two classes:

```java
package ExtensionsPackage;

import net.sf.saxon.expr.XPathContext;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.ExtensionFunctionCall;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.ExtensionFunctionDefinition;
import net.sf.saxon.om.Sequence;
import net.sf.saxon.om.StructuredQName;
import net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException;
import net.sf.saxon.value.SequenceType;
import net.sf.saxon.value.StringValue;

public class ImageToBase64 extends ExtensionFunctionDefinition {
    @Override
    public StructuredQName getFunctionQName() {
        return new StructuredQName("ext", "http://example.com/saxon-extension", "imageToBase64");
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType[] getArgumentTypes() {
        return new SequenceType[]{SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING};
    }

    @Override
    public SequenceType getResultType(SequenceType[] suppliedArgumentTypes) {
        return SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING;
    }

    @Override
    public ExtensionFunctionCall makeCallExpression() {
        return new ExtensionFunctionCall() {
            @Override
            public Sequence call(XPathContext context, Sequence[] arguments) throws XPathException {
                String filePath = ((StringValue)arguments[0]).getStringValue();
                // open file and convert to base64 string
                String resultBase64 = "12345";
                return StringValue.makeStringValue(resultBase64);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and according to this [stackoverflow-entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860654/how-to-register-saxon-xslt-extension-functions-such-that-they-accessible-in-base) another class `MyTransformerFactory`:

```java
package ExtensionsPackage;

import net.sf.saxon.Configuration;
import net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.ExtensionFunctionDefinition;

public class MyTransformerFactory extends TransformerFactoryImpl {
    public MyTransformerFactory() {
        super();
        ExtensionFunctionDefinition imageToBase64Function = new ImageToBase64();
        this.getProcessor().registerExtensionFunction(imageToBase64Function);
    }

    public MyTransformerFactory(Configuration config) {
        super(config);
        ExtensionFunctionDefinition imageToBase64Function = new ImageToBase64();
        this.getProcessor().registerExtensionFunction(imageToBase64Function);
    }
}
```

Now build a `jar` file and throw it into the `lib` folder of Apache FOP.

Then add `set CUSTOMOPTS=-Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=ExtensionsPackage.MyTransformerFactory`
to the `fop.bat` and add `%CUSTOMOPTS%` to `:runFop`.

Add the namespace to your stylesheet:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:ext="http://example.com/saxon-extension">
```

and use it like:

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="ext:imageToBase64('my/file/path')"/>
```

If fop.bat now gets executed via console `xsl:value-of` will deliver `12345`.